JPA insert objects with null ids
I have the following entities :
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Collection<AddressEntity> adresses;

    public void addAddresses(Collection<AddressEntity> ad) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
        addresses.forEach(address-> address.setUser(this));
    }

}

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "address")
public class AddressEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private Integer userId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private UserEntity user;

}

And I save the entities by calling the userRepository :
users.addAdresses(addresses);
userRepository.saveAll(users);

When the user and the addresses don't already exist in the database, I have the following error :
ERROR - ERROR: null value in column "user_id" of relation "address" violates not-null constraint

What do I miss here ?

can you add code explaining how you are saving the objects?
I mean, in the following code that you have added,
users.addAdresses(addresses); userRepository.saveAll(users);
can you update how you are creating/getting addresses and users. This will help to simulate the exact issue.

@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
private Integer userId;

Above code is creating the problem here. You can remove the userId field of AddressEntity as it is not required. JoinColumn annotation added on user field of AddressEntity creates user_id column and saves id of UserEntity.
You can read more about JoinColumn annotation here - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-column.
I executed the following code after removing the userId field from AddressEntity, and I get the below results.
    UserEntity user1 = new UserEntity();
    UserEntity user2 = new UserEntity();
    List<AddressEntity> addresses1 = List.of(new AddressEntity(), new AddressEntity());
    List<AddressEntity> addresses2 = List.of(new AddressEntity(), new AddressEntity());
    user1.addAddresses(addresses1);
    user2.addAddresses(addresses2);
    userRepository.saveAll(List.of(user1, user2));

User Table:



ID




1


2



Address Table:



ID
USER_ID




1
1


2
1


3
2


4
2




I removed the userId, unfortunately I still have the same error. I even removed the (optional = false) on the @ManyToOne annotation, but still same issue. Also, the generated SQL insert query doesn't contain the "user_id" field anymore

Actually I removed the "referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false" part and it worked ! Any clue why it worked like this ?

Oh, that seems strange. Could you share your whole code if possible via github link? In my local, it is working even after just removing userId, so I am not able to simulate the issue. Glad you found the fix though
